# PHP Mail function, BCC not working

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out why the bcc part of this PHP mail function is not working in the code below:

```
function _send_user_email($to, $subject, $message) {
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Customer Service <support@mydomain.com>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: <support@mydomain.com>";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
```

I wouldn't think that there should be any problem specifying a bcc email address that is the same as the From address, but I'm not sure.

When I test this function, the recipient receives the message, but the BCC copy does not come through.  Any idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a unique BCC address?

Comment: Why are you using an array for `$headers`?

Comment: The only reason I am using an array is because it is just some code that I found somewhere.  It seemed to make sense to me, so I figured why not?

Comment: With an array and using implode you avoid having to add the "\r\n" to each header line. Better legibility and less error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, don't use the `mail()` function -- you're just letting yourself into a world of hurt.

If you want to do anything beyond absolutely the most basic email, I strongly recommend using a decent mail class, [such as phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

It will make things much easier. No more messing around building the headers yourself, or trying to get the mime types working. Sending to multiple addresses, CC and BCC addresses becomes simple, and adding attachments goes from virtually impossible with `mail()` to dead simple.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks spudley.  That's just the type of advice i was looking for.  I'll start using the phpMailer.  I hope it's easy to learn . . .

Comment: I've always came back running to the default mail. No matter what, it always works. If you can deal with a very complicated PHP mail, then it's fine. I spent half a day trying to get phpmailer to work. It was basically missing a bunch of functionality and class files, which I finally got working. My web host didn't like it, even though it worked locally. It was such a headache, but the code looked really neat and clean. In the end, mail works.

Answer (score 2):

try this one in your script you have to change `""` to `''` and also remove `<>` then it will be work here i edited your script

```
function _send_user_email($to, $subject, $message) { 
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Customer Service <support@mydomain.com>";
$headers[] = 'Bcc: support@mydomain.com';
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
```

**here my mail function example**

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "From: mydemo.com<$your_email>\r\n" .  
$headers .= 'Bcc: mydemo@mydemo.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Now If You Want To Use Html In Message**

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 

For Exampe Message
$message .='<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Cci like this example:

```
$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Cci' => $bcc,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
```

Answer (score -1):

it working fine, i have tested the script found that email drop in Junk box.

try to add name of email holder :

```
"Bcc: Support <support@mydomain.com>";
```